# Quartz prevent jobs overlap

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I am new with Quartz 2.1 and have a question about it. I have a Job as below

```
@PersistJobDataAfterExecution
@DisallowConcurrentExecution
public class HelloJob implements Job {

    public void execute(JobExecutionContext arg0) throws JobExecutionException {
```

and I create 2 jobs as below

```
JobDetail jobDetail = JobBuilder.newJob(HelloJob.class).withIdentity("Job1").build();
JobDetail jobDetail2 = JobBuilder.newJob(HelloJob.class).withIdentity("Job2").storeDurably().build();
Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().forJob(jobDetail).withSchedule(
                        SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule()
                                .withIntervalInSeconds(5).repeatForever()).build();
Trigger trigger2 = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().forJob(jobDetail2).withSchedule(
                        SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule()
                                .withIntervalInSeconds(10).repeatForever()).build();
        SchedulerFactory factory = new StdSchedulerFactory("quartz.properties");
        Scheduler scheduler = factory.getScheduler();
        scheduler.start();
        scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
        scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail2, trigger2);
```

As you see, job1 executes every 5 seconds, job2 executes every 10 seconds. What I want is, if job1 take more than 10 seconds to done, the job2 will execute until job1 finish. But actually, job2 still execute while job1 not done. Could youplease help me?

```
P/s: this is the quartz.properties:
org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 2
org.quartz.threadPool.threadsInheritContextClassLoaderOfInitializingThread = true
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are using the same job you need only one JobDetail instance (not two).
2. Call storeDurably for you JobDetail.
3. Set the same jobDetail for trigger and trigger2
4. Schedule job as the following:

   ```
   scheduler.start();
   scheduler.addJob(jobDetail, true);
   scheduler.scheduleJob(trigger);
   scheduler.scheduleJob(trigger2);
   ```

Other part of your code is good.